# How to make Ajax delete Django's object instance?

Tags: python, django, ajax

There is a list generated in HTML, that represents all objects (Cards).
 There is already a delete button, but it's using Django functionality, and it requires a page to reload to take effect.
 Is there a simple way to include AJAX into the program?

I am a beginner to JavaScript and AJAX. I have tried some copy-paste solutions. I even tried to deconstruct a simple Django Ajax CRUD app, but it has too many functionalities, and it seemed like an overkill for my app (i would have to rewrite all the views, templates and urls).
 So I decided to ask a question over here with my own code.

views.py (List objects view)

```
def all_cards(request):
    cards = Card.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'all_cards.html', {'cards':cards})
```

all_cards.html

```
 <body>
    {% if cards %}
    <table class="table" id="card-table">
      <tr>
        <th>Card owner name</th>
        <th>Card balance</th>
      </tr>
      {% for card in cards %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ card.cardholders_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ card.card_balance }}€</td>
        <td><form action="{% url 'card_delete' card.id %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="submit" value='Delete'>
      </form></td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
      <p>There are no cards registered.</p>
      {% endif %}
    </table>
  </body>
```

urls.py

```
    url(r'(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.card_delete, name='card_delete'),
```

views.py (Delete object view)

```
def card_delete(request, id):
    card_that_is_ready_to_be_deleted = get_object_or_404(Card, id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        card_that_is_ready_to_be_deleted.delete()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/all_cards')
```

As you can see, the form's input(
`<input type="submit" value='Delete'>`
)calls Django's view via URL.

I expect the delete button to call an AJAX functionality, that will do a similar thing.

How should I go about writing that functionality?

P.S.: This is my first StackOVerflow question, I'm open for constructive criticism.

Comment: is any error appear ?if not , you need debug it.first try to found `def card_delete(request, id):` is calling when you press button or not.for this you can adding `print("I am in view")` to above of code in card_delete function.

Comment: @mehdi The above code works. My question was about writing the same functionality in AJAX. Check out Saeed Alijani's answer to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add *id* to your form and table row first

```
<form action="{% url 'card_delete' card.id %}" method="post" id="delete_form_{{ card.id }}">
```

.

```
<tr id="card_{{card.id}}">
```

And change button code to:

```
<input type="button" onclick="submit_delete({{ card.id }})" value="delete">
```

And use this function to send AJAX request:

```
<script>
  function submit_delete(id) {
      $.ajax({
          type: $('#delete_form_'+id).attr('method'),
          url: $('#delete_form_'+id).attr('action'),
          data: $('#delete_form_'+id).serialize(),
          success: function (data) {
              $('#card'+id).remove()
          }
      });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: But now I have ran into a new problem. The AJAX does delete the database object, but I still have to refresh the page, to see the changes in HTML. Are there any known solutions? Like, for example, putting the whole table inside a container that refreshes after AJAX submit...

Comment: in success part in ajax add this line: `location.reload();` .so your `success` part should be like this :` success: function (data) {    $('#card'+id).remove();location.reload(); } `

Comment: @mehdi I used ```             $("#all_cards_table").load("all_cards.html #all_cards_table")
``` in the script, and it works too! But still, thanks for the input, It helped alot!